# Is there a free wpf grid that behaves like normal grid like the DataGridView in winforms?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a free wpf grid that behaves like normal grid like the DataGridView in winforms?

The WPF DataGrid can't be indexed by row, column like a normal grid control instead it uses bound List's of T.

I need a grid (preferably one that support virtualised data) that allows row, col indexing to get/set values.

Thanks

Comment: can you please describe what you wanna do in your app, just for better understanding.

Comment: The WPF grid does it that way because the times have changed and things are done differently now... you should (just about) never need to index into a grid directly like that just to get data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest and simplest way to do it, is to embed a DataGridView in a wpf control. However you'll lose all the wpf benefits.